# What Google drive api authentication method do I use for software that will be self hosted by many?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am attempting to write a plugin for the music server Ampache that will allow users to use their music files in Google drive. I have looked through some of the docs for Google drive, and I am a little stuck.

All of the Oath methods seem to require a fixed domain which isn't possible because each user hosts Ampache on their own servers. I thought about giving instructions for them to set up their own service account access, but I can't find a tutorial that is for my use case. The code will be in PHP. The way modules work in Ampache, it is not practical to store a file for the module to access. Each module gets a configuration page where one would normally just enter their API key and secret or whatever. Is there a way to access Google Drive like this for each user?

Is it possible to sidestep the authenticated domain with Oauth, or would it be better for each user to set up their own service account? If the latter, I would like a link to some good documentation on how it is accomplished.

Also, if a library is suggested it must be accessible from Composer.
Thanks all.

Comment: use native / other authorization.  I would not expect that it would work out of the box with the google php client library its probably not a use case they have considered you may have to contact them for direction.   Your still going to have to download the files to play them you know.  Your not going to be able to stream them from Google drive its just a file storage api.

Comment: What is the final objective? As DalmTo said, it's not possible a to do a streaming service.

Comment: Normally Ampache will download the file and transcode it before streaming it to the client. I do not need transcoding. I intend to modify Ampache to send a link to the file on Google Drive directly to the client who can then download it.